# Cannot find module './gm'

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I've installed the npm gm as the tutorial says.

https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

I installed gm with homebrew and after that I installed the npm.

Now when I'm trying to use this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
, gm = require('./gm');
```

This is my Code to append images:

```
gm(dir+"img/slots/test1.png").append(dir+"test2.png").write(dir+'appended.png',     function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

It tells me Cannot find module './gm'

Edit: it works now seems like I had the wrong syntax

```
gm(dir+'test1.png')
    .append(dir+'test2.png')
    .autoOrient()
    .write(dir+'newIMAGE.png', function (err) {
        if (err) return handle(err);
        console.log('Created an image from a Buffer!');
    });
```

Was the way to go
Thanks for all answers
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You should be using `require('gm')` if you installed it with NPM.

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried but now it doesnt do any of the gm stuff..

Comment: Im using gm.append which should append images to another

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to take a crack at this. For Mac users. I bet Windows might be same solution.

I installed GM by downloading and decompressing and making the source. Install worked and confirmed in terminal `gm version`. `require('gm')` didn't work.

I then installed GM via NPM and tried globally (`npm install gm -g`). I see it installed (`npm install -d`) but still `require('gm')` doesn't work.

I then went to ***local*** directory where the script is located in terminal and NPM installed there. `npm install gm` and `require('gm')` worked.

Oh, make sure to update NPM. You should run this with permissions `sudo npm i -g npm` on windows you will need to open cmd with admin privileges.